# how to hide and show another iframe from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```html
<div class="category-tab" id="navg"><!--category-tab-->
<div class="col-sm-15">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
       
   <li class="active" ><a href="link"  data-toggle="tab">name</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#link" data-toggle="tab">name</a></li>           <li ><a href="#link" data-toggle="tab">name</a</li>
   <li ><a href="#link" data-toggle="tab">name</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
</div>


<iframe src="" id="a" height="2000" width="1366" frameborder="0" align="right" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
<iframe src="" id="b" height="2000" width="1366" frameborder="0" align="right" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

what i want is when click the link  
inside the li tag

it toggle the iframe or show and hide any way just the idea that i can make iframe connect with the link above

when i click on link it become active then , the iframe connect with it load instead of the other

Comment: Please format your HTML and correct the typos in it (for instance one of your `a` tags is not properly closed). Thanks!

Comment: Not really clear what's expected. There are more links than iframes and no relationship mentioned between iframe and links.

Comment: Why don't we create `tabs` and put iframe in the `TabContent` section!? That will be easy enough to work with DIV instead with iframe.

Comment: @MarmiK can you give me an example Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "toggle the iframe to show or hide" you could use [jQuery's toggle-Function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
Then you could write for instance:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe#a').toggle()">I'm a toggle-link.</a><br />
<a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe#b').toggle()">I'm another toggle-link.</a><br />

<iframe id="a" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe><br />
<iframe id="b" src="http://www.wikipedia.org"></iframe>
```

By using .toggle() you're basically just setting the display-property of the iframe to block/none.

**Edit:**
Seems like you want to display only a single iframe at the same time.
Then you could hide all iframes once the user has clicked the link and show only the according one:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#a').show();">I'm a toggle-link (Stack Overflow).</a><br />
<a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#b').show();">I'm another toggle-link (Wikipedia).</a><br />
<a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#c').show();">And another toggle-link (jQuery).</a><br />

<iframe id="a" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe id="b" src="http://www.wikipedia.org" style="display:none"></iframe>
<iframe id="c" src="http://jquery.com" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to hide those iframes you don't want to be shown from the beginning, eg. by putting `style="display:none"` on them.

Comment: You're welcome; glad I could help.

Comment: If this was facebook i would to make like :D